# Screen translation flicker in IPad using phonegap and MGWT

Tags: html, ipad, css, cordova, mgwt

I meet a problem on mgwt development and wanna ask for help here. I am developing an application using MGWT and phonegap. And there will be some animation which will interact with user like swiping a panel with an background image. I implemented it by using Css translation. It works fine in browser(both chrome and safari) and in iphone.  I use MGWT to create the home page with a scrollPanel in the middle, after clicking the items in the scrollPanel, a touchPanel will swipe to the center to cover the homePage. This swiping animation is done by Css translate3d(x,y,z).

However, when I deploy the application to iPad 4, the background color(using css) start flickering during the panel translation.  the scrollPanel in the home screen keep flickering for around one seconde( I guess it is rendering), part of the items disappear and the part of the white background ground is show. The problem also appear in the touchPanel's content. I tried some suggested solution like hardware acceleration using translate3d(0,0,0) but seems it doesn't work.

Do any body know why? Please help, thank you.

Comment: how big is the background image you are using, on which iPad is this happening?

Comment: I have revise my question for more details. I am testing it on iPad4 and now use background color only. but still not working.

Comment: can you post a simplified example of your code and css that reproduces this?

Comment: I finally figure out that it is graphic card issue. can be resolved by reducing the number of div and animation